# Create dynamic classes with their fields in python

Tags: python-3.x

In c# I used to use the codedom to generate dynamic classes in new files with their field.

I look for something similar in python I did not find.

What exactly I'm looking for is a class generator app for exemple: the user give me a json file containing classes name and their filed, so I create foreach class a new file and insied it I declare this class and I declare their field.
I will do the for django rest framwork

exemple:

```
python make_app myfile.json this will generate

class ClassNameModel()
field1 = models.CharField()
........
```

So is there any library or any solution for that

Here an exemple of my json file.

```
{
    "create_new_project" : true,
    "app_name": "MyAppName",
    "models": [
        {
            "model_name":  "employee", 
            "fields": [
                {"key":"name", "type": "CharField"},
                {"key":"user_id", "type": "IntegerField"},
                {"key":"active", "type": "BooleanField"}
                ]
            
        },
        {
            "model_name":  "salariee",
            "fields": [
                {"key":"name", "type": "CharField"},
                {"key":"salair", "type": "IntegerField"},
                {"key":"active", "type": "BooleanField"}
                ]
        }
        ]
}
```

I read models node and foreach model_name I create new file.
In that file I create my class.

and here how I generate classes now "I don't like this because it's hard coded'

```
def create_models_file(app_name):
    '''
    Create a 'model.py' file inside the folder from the current django app
    
    '''
   
    #here i got the fields form models
    
    fields = models[app_name]
#here I create my imports and I create the class
    models_file_content = ('from django.db import models\n'
                           'from django.db.models import Model\n\n\n'

                           f'class  {app_name}Model(models.Model):\n'
                        )
    
    
   #here I create fields
    list_fields = ""
    for a,v in fields.items():
        key = v[0]['key']
        value = v[0]['type']
        tempString = f"   {key} = models.{value}()\n"
        list_fields += tempString

    models_file_content += list_fields 
    
#Here I create a file and wirte in it the content
        with open(os.path.join(app_name, 'models.py'), 'w') as file:
            file.write(models_file_content)
```

All of this is hard coded, is there other way please?

Comment: Dynamically creating classes in Python is trivial (indeed, all classes are created dynamically! Python is a dynamic language), so there is probably no comparable library, although, some libraries might provide utilities similar to what you want. But again, you can just write the Python code to do this.

Comment: Frankly, you should *describe your problem*. You need to create some classes with particular fields according to some JSON? Can you provide an example JSON and a specification for how the JSON is supposed to map to a class? Then we could show you how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes dynamically in python using the `type` builtin function.

```py
class Base:
    
    def base_function(self):
        print("inherited function")


MyClass = type("MyClass", (Base,), {"field1": models.CharField()}}
```

You should be able to loop through your json dictionary and procedurally generate the class name and class attribute dictionary based on the field names. Technically, you can also create class methods and enter them into the attribute dictionary that is provided as the third argument to `type`, but it's usually easier to just define those in a base class and inherit from it using the `bases` 2nd argument to `type`.